# how to detect iPad3 in an app / game

Tags: objective-c, ipad

Does anyone know a way to detect iPad 3? 
Does the `5.0` version of `iOS SDK` has a function for this?

Thanks!

Comment: how would you test the code even if there was something like that?

Comment: @Vin: I know that I'm not able to test it but what I'd like to place is the conditions for resources (images); any other ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The iPad 3 isn't out yet so you wouldn't know what its model identifier is; however, what you can do is get the model identifier and if it starts with "iPad" and isn't any of the known models, you can assume/guess it is an iPad 3 (at least in the near future).

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>


@implementation UIDevice (Hardware)

- (NSString *) platform {

    size_t size;
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
    char *machine = malloc(size);
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
    NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithCString:machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    free(machine);
    return platform;
}

@end
```

So you just call [UIDevice platform] and compare it to the know iPad models:

- iPad1,1: iPad 1
- iPad2,1: iPad 2 (WiFi)
- iPad2,2: iPad 2 (3G, GSM)
- iPad2,3: iPad 2 (3G, CDMA)

Anything else starting with iPad should be a new model.

For all iPad models, [go here](http://www.everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=iPad).

Comment: Thank you! I'll take in consideration your answer and look up forward, cheers! :D